# shared memory with more than one process

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm having a problem in shared memory that is :
the project is to define number of ports and let these ports interconnect with each other,
i must implement these ports by one of the inter-communication methods in ubuntu (pipes, shared memory, message queue and so on), so i decided to implement them as shared memory with number of segments equal to number of ports.

my problem here is when i attache the shared memory with the same key and same ID with different processes the shmat() function returns different pointer to the same shared memory !
so each process has its own shared memory ! ... why this is happen ? thanks

```
int ringget(key_t key, int size, ring_t* info)
{
int shm_ID = shmget(key, sizeof(struct info)*size, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
if(shm_ID == -1)
{
    return -1;
}
info->shm_ID = shm_ID;
int msgID = msgget(key+1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
info->msgID = msgID;
info->shm_size = size;
return 0;
}

int ringat(ring_t* info, int port)
{
if((port-1) >= 0 && (port-1) <= info->shm_ID)
{
    int y;
    int id = info->shm_ID;
    printf("the shared memory ID is [%i]\n", id);
    struct info* i;
    i = (struct info*) shmat(id, NULL, 0);
    i->port = 55;
    printf("the base address is [%p]\n", i);
    struct info * ptr = i;
    for(y = 0; y<info->shm_size; y++)
    {
        (ptr+y)->PID = 0;
        (ptr+y)->port = 0;
    }
    info->ptr = i+port-1;
    (info->ptr)->port = port;
    (info->ptr)->PID = getpid();
        printf("The port is [%i] and the PID is [%i] and the pointer address is [%p]\n",                 (info->ptr)->port, (info->ptr)->PID,(info->ptr));
    printf("DONE\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("out of range\n");
    return -1;
}
 }
```

Comment: You need to show some code if you expect anyone to do anything but guess what is going on.

Comment: You should add error checking code and perror errors to eliminate any obvious problems.

Comment: but there's no error, the problem is the function shmat() returns different pointers to the same shared memory

Comment: As Andrew pointed out, that's not actually a problem.  The problem is that you said changes are not reflected in different processes.  Where do you get "key" from that you add 1 for each subsequent segment?  Is it possible you are attaching the same memory multiple times?

Comment: i send the key in the main and it was 15 but i tried to change it in the message queue hopefully it solves the problem so you can ignore (key+1) in the msgget()

Comment: if i want to use shared memory i must attache it, and that was what i done :\

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly normal. On modern operating systems with protected memory, every process has an independent virtual address space. It is expected that shared memory segments will be mapped to different virtual addresses in each process. The shared memory segment is still backed by the same physical pages for each process.

Comment: but when i write on the shared memory the other process doesn't see the changes because it has its own copy ! ...

Comment: That should not happen if you're using the same ID in each process. Show us the code (just a minimal example that demonstrates the problem) if you want further help.

Comment: i just get the shared memory with the same key and attache it with the same id back from the get function in each process, how can this be wrong ?

Comment: do i must get and attache the shared memory with the same function ?

Comment: One line is not enough to diagnose the problem. Please edit a *minimal*, *compilable* example into your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new here :(